# $x,y,z>0$ and $x+y+z=1$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

$x,y,z>0$ and $x+y+z=1$. Prove:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{x^{5}+y^{4}z}{y+z}\geq \frac{1}{27}$$
My tried was to add $3$ and to homogenize with $x + y + z$. Another tried was to write LHS as $\sum_{cyc} \frac{x^{5}}{y+z}+\sum _{cyc}\frac{y^{4}z}{y+z}$.

Comment: Spiltting up the terms should work. What have you tried in that regard? Can you show that $ xy+yz+zx \leq 1/3 $?

Comment: From inequality $(x+y+z)^{2}\geq 3(xy+yz+xz)$ we get $xy+yz+xz\leq \frac{1}{3}$

Comment: Ah, seems like $ \sum y^4z/ ( y + z) \leq 1/54$, so splitting doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Split the terms as

$$ \sum \frac{ x^5 - y^5 } { y+z } + \sum \frac{ y^5 + y^4 z } { y+z} \geq \frac{1}{27}.$$

> Show that
>  1. the first summation is $ \geq 0$, (If stuck, see comments)
>  2. the second summation is $ \sum y^4 \geq \frac{1}{27}$.

---

I'm not quite satisfied with this solution because the splitting seems "magical", though I know what steps / similar problems motivated the approach.
I would like to see another distinct-enough (non brute-force) approach.

The issue with $ \sum \frac{ y^4 z } { y+ z }$ is that because of the cross terms, it could get too low (even close to 0, like with $ x =y = \epsilon \rightarrow 0 , z = 1 - 2 \epsilon$).
In the event this happens, the $ \sum \frac{ x^5 } { y+z }$ term would have gotten large, and so we need to "share" it across the split.
Adding a $y^5$ term in the numerator of the second term helps us to factor it, leaving a no-cross-term $y^4$ that makes the split ultimately work.
We then have to subtract a $y^5$ term in the numerator of the first term, and check if it truly satisfies the desired bound.

Comment: This looks nice enough (+1) though you may want to add another spoiler that $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{x^5}{y+z}\ge \sum_{cyc}\frac{y^5}{y+z}$$ is true by the rearrangement ineqality  and leave the OP to see how the rearrngemnt works.It took me some time to see how the sum is greater than zero.Also   i think the author of this inequality made up this inequality with the magic in mind so i guess this would be the best solution

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore I considered that, and would have given that as a hint if OP was still stuck. I was tempted to state "by rearrangement" (without moving the term over).  This is part of the "I know what similar problems motivated the approach", where I felt that was a simple enough olympiad problem for OP to work on (E.g. similar to "Nesbitt via rearrangement"), given how quickly they responded to my initial comment.